# Will this Garbage Disposal to P Trap height work?

Tags: kitchens, sink, garbage-disposal

Recently purchased a retrofit farm sink and went to hook the garbage disposal back up. After roughing everything back up because the farm sink sets much lower I am wondering about drainage and if this setup is acceptable. What do you think? [image]

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81969/what-is-the-minimum-height-for-garbage-disposal-drain-above-the-drain-stub

Comment: The drain pipe coming out of the wall is lower than the outlet of the disposal so it is good to go. **+1 for a well lit photo under a sink**. In the future if you use the search function of this site you may find the same or similar questions with correct  answers.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This will be closed soon as a duplicate;  you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.